# Is it true that Mother Lakshmi married Lord Vishnu because She thought He was the best?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, lakshmi

(I read this long back,so I cannot verify whether this true,even Google searches seem in vain.)

Is it true that **Mother Lakshmi thought Lord Vishnu was the best among deities,and so wedded Him?**

I feel like Mother says so,(much) after their wedding;in flashback.

What was Lord Vishnu‘a comment on this?(I feel like Lord Vishnu spoke something about Lord Shiva,but I’m not sure)